# How to parse property value in properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

Hi
I am loading a property file to establish DB connection,
ex:

```
DB1="JDBc................", username , password
```

above line is as in property file, but when i call getConnection method I need to send url, username and pw.
How can I parse it.

Comment: why not separating this into several properties (url, username, password)

Comment: I don't get the problem... split the string by comma and that's it. If the first part is a jdbc URL, the rest is simple. But as lweller said, you should use three properties in that case.

Answer (score 10):

You can put your key/value pairs in a properties file like this:

```
dbUrl = yourURL
username = yourusername
password = yourpassword
```

Then you can load them into your app from the properties file:

```
private void loadProps() {
    try {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("database_props.properties");
        props = new Properties();
        props.load(is);
        is.close();
        dbConnStr = props.getProperty("dbUrl");
        username = props.getProperty("username");
        password = props.getProperty("password");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        log.error("IOException in loadProps");
        for(StackTraceElement ste : ioe.getStackTrace())
        log.error(ste.toString());
    }
}
```

And then you can use those values to create your connection.

Comment: Some solutions use `getClass().getResourceAsStream` whilst others do `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can split the entry:

   ```
   String dbProperty = prop.getProperty("DB1");   
   String[] dbDetails = dbProperty.split(",", 3);
   ```

`dbDetails[0]` will hold your `JDBC...`, `[1]` your `username` and `[2]` your `password`

2. Better still, you might want to hold them in different properties (As lweller said)

   ```
   db.username = scott  
   db.password = tiger  
   db.url = ....
   ```

This way you get better clarity and control.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to define separately

```
dburl =....
username =....
password = ...
```

Still if you want to parse it, you can use the split method of string to split by comma